# QGIS - Add layer that is Editable and with Add Polygon Feature selected

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to add a layer in QGIS that is editable and has Add Polygon Feature selected (by default). I can easily accomplish the editable part by this command:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "temporary_points", "memory")
layer.startEditing()
#Something more here?
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

A bonus question is why it takes extremely long time to get the saving popup when I have that as a part of my code? (and none when I run it from the Python Console)

Comment: Not sure about your bonus question - what do you mean the saving popup? Can you edit your question to show this line of code?

Comment: The "problem" was that I declared the variable `self.layer = QgsVectorLayer(...)` in that part of the code. The solution was to make no changes in that part but just add a `self.layer = None` in the init function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to select Add Polygon feature programmatically:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "temporary_points", "memory")
layer.startEditing()
qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger() #Yep, something here.
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```